# Angular @Input value not changing when changed from Parent Component

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, ngonchanges, ngzone

I have added same child component three times in a single parent component
[image]

And below is the change function called on one of the children's components to change the `selectedName` in other two child components
The `@Input` is type of string if I change it to object it work fine.

[image]

And this is how child component looks like
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue seems to be one of **value** vs. **reference** types.

The reason it works as an Object is that Objects are **reference** types: when you pass an Object to a component, you are passing its **reference**, not a "copy". That means that when you mutate that Object (in a child, for example), any component with a reference to that Object will "see" the change.

The same isn't true for **value** types. When you pass a string, number, or boolean to a component, you are passing the **value**, completely unlinked from the source variable.

You shouldn't be mutating something inside a child component which is relied upon by its siblings and/or parents. You should either be using a service (with methods for mutation) or an @Output to bubble the change event upwards from the child.

Comment: So, you're saying change detection won't work for value types?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the value you modify in a sibling is a value, not a reference to the variable in the parent. That means you can't change a value received by a child and expect the parent's value to change as well. Even if you COULD do that (as you technically can with reference types), it would be terrible code smell. Angular best practice is to use either a service or an @Output. (You could technically also use Redux Actions, if using something like NgRx or Ngxs).

Comment: Alright, I have also witnessed a strange behavior where for value-types it does detect changes for the first time. But no detection after that. Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like more incorrect architecture. You won't have any of those problems if you follow Angular best practices :-)